# Android Alarm - How to get time in milliseconds

Tags: android, time, calendar, alarm

I am trying to do multiple alarms that get times from database and set it on alarm that will most ring every day on the same time, for a specified duration (i.e.: at 15:00 for 5 days). Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class OCalendar {

    public int vRepeatAfter;
    public String vMessage;
    public Calendar vCalendar;
    /*
     * 0 = never stops
     */
    public int vStopAfter =0;
    public int vRaised = 0;

    public void CancelAlarm (int id) {
        MainActivity.ALARM_MANAGER.cancel(MainActivity.ARY_PENDING_INTENTS.get(id));
        // Reset All
        MainActivity.ARY_CALNEDARS.get(id).vRaised = 0;
    }
}
```

Fire alarm:

```
public void fireAlarm() {
    ALARM_MANAGER = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        OCalendar ocalendar = new OCalendar();
        ocalendar.vCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        ocalendar.vCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        ocalendar.vCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        ocalendar.vCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 42);
        ocalendar.vRepeatAfter= 1000;
        ocalendar.vStopAfter = 3;
        ocalendar.vMessage ="Dont Forget To Take Your Medicines";
        ARY_CALNEDARS.add(ocalendar);
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i< ARY_CALNEDARS.size() ; i++) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        OCalendar clndr = ARY_CALNEDARS.get(i);
        // Loop counter `i` is used as a `requestCode`
        intent.putExtra("id", i); // id of the alarm.
        intent.putExtra("AlarmMsg",  clndr.vMessage.toString() );
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, 0);
        ALARM_MANAGER.setRepeating( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP  , 
        ARY_CALNEDARS.get(i).vCalendar.getTimeInMillis() , clndr.vRepeatAfter, pendingIntent);
        ARY_PENDING_INTENTS.add(pendingIntent);
    }
```

On the code given I have a problem with receiving the time in milliseconds here: `ARY_CALNEDARS.get(i).vCalendar.getTimeInMillis()`. I need it to set the calendar time.

Thank you!

Comment: I would strongly recommend to user JodaTime (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for any Java Data/Time operations. It will save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: why dont you create a long object instead and save it to it, and retrieve it later, your code you have will not give you what you earlier did with `ocalendar.vCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());`